# In-Memory Unit Tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I'm attempting to do in-memory testing. I'm following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider).

The article provides [this template](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/samples/core/Testing/TestingWithoutTheDatabase/InMemoryBloggingControllerTest.cs) for setting up an in-memory test.

My problem is occurring with the following section of the code in the template.

```
    BloggingContext CreateContext() => new BloggingContext(_contextOptions, (context, modelBuilder) =>
    {
    #region ToInMemoryQuery
    modelBuilder.Entity<UrlResource>()
        .ToInMemoryQuery(() => context.Blogs.Select(b => new UrlResource { Url = b.Url }));
    #endregion
    });
```

When I customize the template to include my DbContext rather than the example BloggingContext I receive the following compiler error.

"[Your context] does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments".

My question isn't about what the error message means, I know that. My question is, is there a way to achieve what this code is trying to achieve that matches the constructor of my context?

My DbContext has a parameterless constructor and a constructor that looks like this:

```
public [MyContext](DbContextOptions<[MyContext]> options) : base(options)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The linked section of the docs starts with _"using the in-memory provider for testing is strongly discouraged; "_. Is there any reason why not to use something better suited for the goal then in-memory provider?

Comment: Haha! I know. I brought that up in the meeting and what I was told was that for our purposes this testing would be best.

Comment: Suggest using the SQLite, it also can be run in-memory)

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, we use vendor specific functions in our model binding that SQLite doesn't like.